# Convert image to CSV with 8*8 pixel using R programmimg

Tags: r

```
library("EBImage")
img <- readImage("sample.jpg")    
img <- channel(img, "grey")
write.csv(t(img), "sample.csv", row.names = FALSE)
```

I'm using the above code to convert my image to csv.My image size is 32*32 and i got 1024 features(columns) in csv with 1 observation. But I want to take an 8*8 block from the whole image and write each 8*8 block as an observation. so finally i should have 64 features and 16 observations.

```
  # Main loop. Loop over each image
  for(i in 1:length(images))
  {
    # Read image
    img <- readImage(images[i])
    # Get the image as a matrix
    img_matrix <- img@.Data
    # Coerce to a vector
    img_vector <- as.vector(t(img_matrix))


  }


  # Write out dataset
  write.csv(img_vector, out_file, row.names = FALSE)
```

Comment: it would be useful to include that the instalation of such package requires
`## try http:// if https:// URLs are not supported`
`source("https://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")`
`biocLite("EBImage")`

Comment: And can you share your sample.jpg image? so we can figure out the output that you are getting?

Comment: Output is correct. I just want to know how to take 8*8 pixel from 32*32  image

Answer (score 0):

Sure there is a more effectively way to do this but you could do it linearly (perhaps not the way that you need it) with a triple for cycle:

```
#Instalation of this package is a little special
source("https://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite("EBImage")
library("EBImage")
img <- readImage("sample.jpg")    
img <- channel(img, "grey")

img0 <- as.vector(img)

new_img<-matrix(ncol=64,nrow=16)

for(i in 1:16){
  for(j in 1:8){
    for(k in 1:8){
      new_img[i,8*(j-1)+k]<-img0[[64*(i-1)+8*(j-1)+k]]
    }
  }
}

write.csv(new_img, "sample.csv", row.names = FALSE)
```

But if you 8*8 blocks are like the squares of a cuadricule the for cycles should go as:

```
img0 <- as.vector(img)

new_img<-matrix(ncol=64)
for(i in 1:4){
  for(j in 1:4){
    vec=vector()
      for(k in 1:8){
        for(l in 1:8){
          vec=c(vec,img0[[256*(i-1)+8*(j-1)+32*(k-1)+l]])
      }
    }
    new_img=rbind(new_img,vec)

  }
}
new_img=new_img[-1,]
```

[image: 32x32 example image]

Comment: by running this code I got 1024 observations and one feature

Comment: it is weird, using the image of the apple I got 16 observations of 64 variables. Sure you are writing the `new_img` matrix to the new file?